# Auditing machine logins with RSA keys vs passwords

Tags: unix, passwords, rsa, audit

My question to the community is this, is one authentication scheme better than the other at leaving an audit trail to see who was on what machine?

Thank you,

-=Bryan

Answer (score 0):

The RSA tokens are strong evidence that the token was present when the authentication took place.  Not proof, but strong evidence.  I think that that in and of itself makes the audit trail a little stronger.  No longer can someone simply claim 'someone must have stolen my password!'

The audit trail itself isn't significantly different though.